# Wrong execution plan in MySQL 8.0 when using JOIN in WHERE NOT IN clause

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-8.0

After a migration from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.34, we have a very strange behavior with a query when `semijoin` is `on` in the optimizer_switch.

###### 1. The problematic query:

```
SELECT COUNT(s0_.id)
FROM stores_shoppers s0_
WHERE s0_.id NOT IN (
    SELECT s4_.id
    FROM emails_history i5_
    INNER JOIN stores_shoppers s4_ ON i5_.shopper_id = s4_.id
    WHERE i5_.rule_id IN (1517676 , 1517677)
)
```

In this case this is the execution plan:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | s0_ | NULL | index | NULL | stores_shoppers_store_id_idx | 4 | NULL | 361627391 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE |  | NULL | eq_ref | <auto_distinct_key> | <auto_distinct_key> | 5 | remarkety_prod.s0_.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where; Not exists |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | i5_ | invalid_dates,p2022m03,... | ALL | emails_history_rule_id_idx | NULL | NULL | NULL | 7526556120 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | s4_ | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | remarkety_prod.i5_.shopper_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

The problem is that the i5_ JOIN type is ALL, no index is used in the JOIN.

###### 2. With only one value in the IN clause:

If the `IN` clause in the query includes only one value:

```
SELECT COUNT(s0_.id)
FROM stores_shoppers s0_
WHERE s0_.id NOT IN (
    SELECT s4_.id
    FROM emails_history i5_
    INNER JOIN stores_shoppers s4_ ON i5_.shopper_id = s4_.id
    WHERE i5_.rule_id IN (1517676) -- only one value
)
```

The execution plan becomes:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | s0_ | NULL | index | NULL | stores_shoppers_store_id_idx | 4 | NULL | 361632497 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE |  | NULL | eq_ref | <auto_distinct_key> | <auto_distinct_key> | 5 | remarkety_prod.s0_.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where; Not exists |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | i5_ | invalid_dates,p2022m03,... | ref | emails_history_rule_id_idx | emails_history_rule_id_idx | 5 | const | 56944 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | s4_ | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | remarkety_prod.i5_.shopper_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

In this case, the JOIN uses an index but the execution plan is still different from the execution plan we have in MySQL 5.7

###### 3. Using i5_.shopper_id instead of s4_.id (which is supposed to be identical)

```
SELECT COUNT(s0_.id)
FROM stores_shoppers s0_
WHERE s0_.id NOT IN (
    SELECT i5_.shopper_id -- using i5_.shopper_id instead of s4_.id
    FROM emails_history i5_
    INNER JOIN stores_shoppers s4_ ON i5_.shopper_id = s4_.id
    WHERE i5_.rule_id IN (1517676 , 1517677)
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | s0_ | NULL | index | NULL | stores_shoppers_store_id_idx | 4 | NULL | 361632516 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | i5_ | invalid_dates,p2022m03,... | range | emails_history_rule_id_idx | emails_history_rule_id_idx | 5 | NULL | 56945 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | s4_ | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | remarkety_prod.i5_.shopper_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

In this case, the execution plan is the same as we had in MySQL 5.7

###### 4. With semijoin=off

```
SET optimizer_switch = 'semijoin=off';
SELECT COUNT(s0_.id)
FROM stores_shoppers s0_
WHERE s0_.id NOT IN (
    SELECT s4_.id
    FROM emails_history i5_
    INNER JOIN stores_shoppers s4_ ON i5_.shopper_id = s4_.id
    WHERE i5_.rule_id IN (1517676 , 1517677)
)
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | s0_ | NULL | index | NULL | stores_shoppers_store_id_idx | 4 | NULL | 361632550 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | i5_ | invalid_dates,p2022m03,... | range | emails_history_rule_id_idx | emails_history_rule_id_idx | 5 | NULL | 56945 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | s4_ | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | remarkety_prod.i5_.shopper_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

Same execution plan as before.

###### Questions:

Can anyone explain to me what's going on ?
Is that a bug in the optimizer ?
Why the join doesn't use index in the first query ?

Comment: What indexes do you have?  Did you try any EXISTS yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem with optimizer_switch** -- File a bug report at bugs.mysql.com

**Recommend adding these indexes:**

```
emails_history:  INDEX(shopper_id, rule_id)
emails_history:  INDEX(rule_id, shopper_id)
```

**Some general tips:**

- `COUNT(x)` tests `x` for being `NOT NULL`.  You probably wanted `COUNT(*)`.
- `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` has long been a poorly optimized construct.  5.7 got better; 8.0 tried to get it even better, but maybe not in this case.
- `IN(1517676)` is optimized as `= 1517676`, but `IN (1517676 , 1517677)` does not optimized as well.  Sometimes a multi-item `IN` is best optimized with `UNION`.
- "semijoin" is probably a synonym of `EXISTS(SELECT ...)`

**Performance thoughts**

I don't understand the goal of the query, but here are some things I would try to do:

- Rewrite the query to avoid using `stores_shoppers` twice.
- Try `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`
- Try `( SELECT ... rule_id = 123 ) UNION ALL ( SELECT ... rule_id = 123 )`

Comment: First of all, thank you for this clear answer. The query is a part of a much larger query generated by doctrine, I only posted this part to show the error we are encountering. That's why the goal is not really clear here.
I followed your advice and rewrote the query without using stores_shoppers a second time and the problem was solved.